# SQL - Complex RANK

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking

Here is a little mind-breaker:

Platform is MS SQL 2008, but the problem is general.

I have a table table with 3 columns:
CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE

```
TABLE1
-------------------------------------------------------
CLIENT      |DATE       |DESTINATION_PREFERENCE
-------------------------------------------------------
Akme        |2014-01    |1
Akme        |2014-02    |6
Akme        |2014-02    |3
Akme        |2014-03    |5
Yutani      |2014-01    |5
Yutani      |2014-02    |8
Yutani      |2014-03    |3
Yutani      |2014-03    |5
```

What I have to do is actually 2 things at once:

**1st is very simple, and a classic problem:**

Selecting the rows with the one minimum DESTINATION_PREFERENCE from each group of CLIENT, and DATE.

In other words, we GROUP BY on CLIENT,DATE, then we choose the rows with the lowest DESTINATION_PREFERENCE.

Note: I use only YEAR and MONTH from the DATE.

This can be easily solved by RANK:

```
    SELECT 
    CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE ORDER BY DESTINATION_PREFERENCE ASC) AS RANKING
        FROM
        #table1
    ) sq
    WHERE
    RANKING = 1
```

Good result is, where we choose rows only with the lowest DESTINATION_PREFERENCE from each group of CLIENT and DATE(YEAR,MONTH):

```
    CLIENT  DATE    DESTINATION_PREFERENCE
    Akma    2014-01 1
    Akma    2014-02 3
    Akma    2014-03 5
    Yutani  2014-01 5
    Yutani  2014-02 8
    Yutani  2014-03 3
```

**2nd - Now comes the hard part. Which I cannot solve, and need some advice:**

If the DESTINATION_PREFERENCE is 3 I should still include rows where 
DESTINATION_PREFERENCE equals to 6.

So the result table value will have one extra row (2nd row):

```
CLIENT  DATE    DESTINATION_PREFERENCE
Akma    2014-01 1
Akme    2014-02 6
Akma    2014-02 3
Akma    2014-03 5
Yutani  2014-01 5
Yutani  2014-02 8
Yutani  2014-03 3
```

How could I extend RANK() to such include arbitrary rules like that?
Example rules to implement:

If the top lowest value of DESTINATION_PREFERENCE is 3 in the group, then include rows with values of 6 as well from the same group.

If the top lowest value of DESTINATION_PREFERENCE is 9 in the group, then include rows with values of 2 as well from the same group.

If the top lowest value of DESTINATION_PREFERENCE is 128 in the group then include rows with values of 312 as well from the same group.

etc ...

There are many rules.

Thank you for the tips in advance!

Comment: Do you ant "6" only if 3 is the *minimum* preference or just if there is a "3" at all?

Comment: If 3 is the minimum in the group, then I want rows with 3 AND all other rows with 6 from the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE with adding additional column, where you simply replace 6 with 3, 9 with 2 etc.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      client NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      date DATETIME ,
      dest INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'Akme', '20140101', 1 ),
        ( 'Akme', '20140102', 3 ),
        ( 'Akme', '20140102', 6 ),
        ( 'Akme', '20140103', 5 ),
        ( 'Yutani', '20140104', 2 ),
        ( 'Yutani', '20140104', 7 ),
        ( 'Yutani', '20140104', 9 ),
        ( 'Yutani', '20140105', 7 );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   client ,
                        date ,
                        dest ,
                        CASE dest
                          WHEN 6 THEN 3
                          WHEN 9 THEN 2
                          ELSE dest
                        END AS rndest
               FROM     @t
             )
    SELECT  CLIENT ,
            DATE ,
            dest
    FROM    ( SELECT    CLIENT ,
                        DATE ,
                        dest ,
                        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE ORDER BY rndest ASC ) AS RANKING
              FROM      cte
            ) sq
    WHERE   RANKING = 1
```

Output:

```
CLIENT  DATE    dest
Akme    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 1
Akme    2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 3
Akme    2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 6
Akme    2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 5
Yutani  2014-01-04 00:00:00.000 2
Yutani  2014-01-04 00:00:00.000 9
Yutani  2014-01-05 00:00:00.000 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that if the *minimum* destination preference is 3, then include 6.  That means treating "6" the same as "3", but only if there is a "3".

You can do this using window functions by putting in a "6-flag":

```
SELECT CLIENT, DATE, DESTINATION_PREFERENCE 
FROM (SELECT t1.*
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE
                          ORDER BY (CASE WHEN NumThrees > 0 AND DESTINATION_PREFERENCE = 6 THEN 3
                                    ELSE DESTINATION_PREFERENCE END) ASC
                         ) AS RANKING
      FROM (SELECT t1.*,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN DESTINATION_PREFERENCE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumThrees
            FROM #table1 t1
           ) t1
    ) sq
WHERE RANKING = 1 ;
```

If you want "6" to be treated as "3" in all circumstances, then you don't need the subquery:

```
SELECT CLIENT, DATE, DESTINATION_PREFERENCE 
FROM (SELECT t1.*
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE
                          ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DESTINATION_PREFERENCE = 6 THEN 3
                                    ELSE DESTINATION_PREFERENCE END) ASC
                         ) AS RANKING
      FROM #table1 t1
    ) sq
WHERE RANKING = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just put a case statement in your order by in the rank:

```
SELECT 
    CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE ORDER BY Case DESTINATION_PREFERENCE when 3 then 6 when 9 then 2 when 128 then 312 else DESTINATION_PREFERENCE END ASC) 
AS RANKING
    FROM
    #table1
) sq
WHERE
RANKING = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can not leave comment to the Gordon Linoff post due to lack of rating. However his solution will work if only 3 is the minimum destination. In case minimum = 1 and it would have both 3 and 6, it will show 6 also.

```
SELECT 
CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE  
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    CLIENT,DATE,DESTINATION_PREFERENCE ,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE ORDER BY DESTINATION_PREFERENCE  ASC) AS RANKING,
    MIN(DESTINATION_PREFERENCE ) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT, DATE) AS min_3
    FROM
    #table1
) sq
WHERE
RANKING = 1 
OR (min_3 = 3 AND DESTINATION_PREFERENCE  =6)
```